# Image histogram implementation with Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I'm tyring to implement (I know there's a custom  function for achieving it) the grayscale image histogram in Matlab, so far I've tried:

```
function h = histogram_matlab(imageSource)
openImage = rgb2gray(imread(imageSource));
[rows,cols] =  size(openImage);

histogram_values = [0:255];

for i = 1:rows
  for j = 1:cols
    p = openImage(i,j);
    histogram_values(p) = histogram_values(p) + 1;

  end
end
histogram(histogram_values)
```

However when I call the function, for example: `histogram_matlab('Harris.png')`

I obtain some graph like:

[image]

which is obviously not what I expect, x axis should go from 0 to 255 and y axis from 0 to whatever max value is stored in `histogram_values`.

I need to obtain something like what `imhist` offers:

[image]

How should I set it up? Am I doing a bad implementation?

### Edit

I've changed my code to improvements and corrections suggested by @rayryeng:

```
function h = histogram_matlab(imageSource)
openImage = rgb2gray(imread(imageSource));
[rows,cols] =  size(openImage);

histogram_values = zeros(256,1)

for i = 1:rows
  for j = 1:cols
    p = double(openImage(i,j)) +1;
    histogram_values(p) = histogram_values(p) + 1;

  end
end
histogram(histogram_values, 0:255)
```

However the histogram plot is not that expected:

[image]

Here it's noticeable that there's some issue or error on y axis as it definitely would reach MORE than 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In terms of calculating the histogram, the computation of the frequency per intensity is correct though there is a slight error... more on that later.  Also, I would personally avoid using loops here.  See my small note at the end of this post.

Nevertheless, there are three problems with your code:

## Problem #1 - Histogram is not initialized properly

`histogram_values` should contain your histogram, yet you are initializing the histogram by a vector of `0:255`.  Each intensity value should **start with a count of 0**, and so you actually need to do this:

```
histogram_values = zeros(256,1);
```

## Problem #2 - Slight error in `for` loop

Your intensities range from 0 to 255, yet MATLAB starts indexing at 1.  If you ever get intensities that are 0, you will get an out-of-bounds error.  As such, the proper thing to do is to take `p` and add it with 1 so that you start indexing at 1.  However, one intricacy I need to point out is that if you have a `uint8` precision image, adding 1 to an intensity of 255 will simply saturate the value to 255.  It won't go to 256.... so it's also prudent that you cast to something like `double` to ensure that 256 will be reached.

Therefore:

```
histogram_values = zeros(256,1);
for i = 1:rows
  for j = 1:cols
    p = double(openImage(i,j)) + 1;
    histogram_values(p) = histogram_values(p) + 1;

  end
end
```

## Problem #3 - Not calling `histogram` right

You should override the behaviour of `histogram` and include the edges.  Basically, do this:

```
histogram(histogram_values, 0:255);
```

The second vector specifies where we should place bars on the `x`-axis.

## Small note

You can totally implement the histogram computation yourself without any `for` loops.  You can try this with a combination of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and two [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) calls:

```
mat = bsxfun(@eq, permute(0:255, [1 3 2]), im);
h = reshape(sum(sum(mat, 2), 1), 256, 1);
```

---

*If you'd like a more detailed explanation of how this code works under the hood, see this conversation between kkuilla and myself: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/conversation/explanation-of-computing-an-images-histogram-vectorized*

However, the gist of it as below.

---

The first line of code creates a 3D vector of 1 column that ranges from 0 to 255 by `permute`, and then using `bsxfun` with the `eq` (equals) function, we use broadcasting so that we get a 3D matrix where each slice is the same size as the grayscale image and gives us locations that are equal to an intensity of interest.  Specifically, the first slice tells you where elements are equal to 0, the second slice tells you where elements are equal to 1 up until the last slice where it tells you where elements are equal to 255.

For the second line of code, once we compute this 3D matrix, we compute two sums - first summing each row independently, then summing each column of this intermediate result.  We then get the total sum per slice which tells us how many values there were for each intensity.  This is consequently a 3D vector, and so we `reshape` this back into a single 1D vector to finish the computation.

---

In order to display a histogram, I would use `bar` with the `histc` flag.  Here's a reproducible example if we use the `cameraman.tif` image:

```
%// Read in grayscale image
openImage = imread('cameraman.tif');
[rows,cols] = size(openImage); 

%// Your code corrected
histogram_values = zeros(256,1);
for i = 1:rows
  for j = 1:cols
    p = double(openImage(i,j)) + 1;
    histogram_values(p) = histogram_values(p) + 1;    
  end
end

%// Show histogram
bar(0:255, histogram_values, 'histc');
```

We get this:

[image]

Comment: Apologies for being thick but I never get `permute`. Why do you permute `[1 3 2]`? Why not `[3 2 1]` for example? You are creating a 3D matrix since you are using three values (i.e. `[1 3 2]`). Why do you want three dimensions? `im` is 2D so why not two dimensions?

Comment: @kkuilla - This is going to take a long time.  I've created a chat room to discuss how `permute` works: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab - FWIW, it took me a while to understand it as well.  Come ping me when you're ready.  I'll be in there.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng could you check my edits, of course it's not like I expect the *exactly* clone of plot generated by `imhist` but it doesn't even look like an *image histogram*. How could I improve it. Also it's obvious it needs adjustments on y axis.

Comment: @diegoaguilar - I wouldn't use `histogram`.  I would use `bar` with the `histc` flag.  I'll update my post.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng. I achieved it, one question, I'm trying to show the implementation, the built in function and finally the image at center, how can I do that? This is what I'm trying: http://kopy.io/1oiuZ

Comment: @kkuilla - You can also do this, assuming `a` has **not** been created yet: `a(1,1,:) = 0:255;`.  This is probably more intuitive than `permute`.

Comment: Yes, I wonder which one is faster. My bet is on `a(1,1,:) = 0:255;`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks correct. The problem is with the call to histogram. You need to supply the number of bins in the call to histogram, otherwise they will be computed automatically.

Try this simple modification which calls stem to get the right plot, instead of relying on histogram

```
function h = histogram_matlab(imageSource)
openImage = rgb2gray(imread(imageSource));
[rows,cols] =  size(openImage);

histogram_values = [0:255];

for i = 1:rows
  for j = 1:cols
    p = openImage(i,j);
    histogram_values(p) = histogram_values(p) + 1;

  end
end
stem(histogram_values); axis tight;
```

**EDIT:** After some inspection of the code you have a 0/1 error. If you have a pixel of value zero then `histogram_value(p)` will give you an index error

Try this instead. No need for vectorization for this simple case:

```
function hv = histogram_matlab_vec(I)

  assert(isa(I,'uint8')); % for now we assume uint8 with range [0, 255]

  hv = zeros(1,256);
  for i = 1 : numel(I)
    p = I(i);
    hv(p + 1) = hv(p + 1) + 1;
  end

  stem(hv); axis tight;
end
```

Comment: Minor note.  `histogram_values` should all be zero initially, but in your secondary function, this is correct.